# How to save data when grid-view radio button is checked?

Tags: c#, asp.net, radio-button

I have a grid view with a radio button field. How can I save data to database, when radio button value is checked. Like let say radio button field is IsDefault. When it is check, I need to save the data to DB. When unchecked, I need to again save the data.

If there is a SAVE button, it is ok. In button lick , I can loop through data row and save data, but how to do same on radio button state change?

Comment: Loop through datarows and insert/update record by record to database

Comment: can you show your code?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `javascript` to get the checked radio button value and store it using ajax.

```
<input type="radio" onclick="RadioClicked(this);"/>
```

add onclick to every radio button, so on clicking any radio button this function gets called.

```
function RadioClicked(x){
    var id = x.id;
    var value = x.value;
    .... // here you can add ajax function to call controller
         // function, and save it to database
}
```